# .net maui ListView don't scroll to added item when binded to ObservableCollection

Tags: maui

I have a maui `ListView` binded to `ObservableCollection`, I expect when I add a new element to the collection my ListView automatically scrolls to that new Item.

But instead my `ListView` doesn't update itself,

I added a CollectionChanged event on my code behind (trying to achieve this), and make a manually scroll when item added but no when I run

```
LstItems.ScrollTo(e.NewItems[e.NewItems.Count - 1], ScrollToPosition.End, false);
```

My ListView goes to the end but it rebuilds all the entire ListView as you can see at [Adding New Item to ListView](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AuOVpatDsfSXnOdbtpOrtQnXckNWiw?e=kySbY8)

I tryed changing `CachingStrategy` to: `RecycleElement`, `RetainElement` but same result.

I tryed using `ScrollToPosition` to `MakeVisible` But same result.

I tryed setting to false the Animation parameter of `ScrollTo` But same result.

My questions:

1. There is a way to make my `ListView` automatically scrolls to the
   new added item? If not:
2. There is a way to manually move to the new
   added item wihtout the UI effect of rebuild the entire ListView?

Comment: Have you tried ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView"?

Comment: @H.A.H. Seems this is not available at maui ListView

Comment: I really isn't big deal to use CollectionView instead. You might even see improvement in performance.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/scrolling?view=net-maui-7.0) to achieve this.

You can scroll to the last item by using the following code:

```
mCollectionView.ScrollTo(myViewModel.Items.Count - 1, animate: true);
```

For more about this, you can check: [Scroll to End](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/scrolling?view=net-maui-7.0#end).